# EXCEL: How to extract variable numbers of numbers from a cell, and figure out a range out of the extracted numbers, only by using FORMULAS?

Tags: excel-formula

I came across a question within which I have to extract variable numbers (1 or 2) of numbers from a cell **only by using formulas.**

I have looked at split functions, and left and right functions, but I don't think they are exactly aligned with my mission. Also, I am finding it challenging to figure out whether a cell contains 1 or 2 numbers by using formulas - no hardcoding.

This column of cells have values such as: `"< 4.00%", "> 8.01%"` or `"4.01%-8.00%"`, and they mean a range of %numbers.

- For the cells with one %number, I only have to extract that 1 value.
- For the cells with two %numbers (i.e. 4.01 and 8.00), I have to extract 2 values.

How should I use **formulas** to extract the ranges (whether a cell has one %number of two - which I also have to figure out by using **formulas**)?

Thank you!

Comment: Show some structured sample data, are the separators consistent?

Comment: Are the quotes part of the numbers?

Comment: please provide more sample data with expected output. do you want the output to be single value or a range of values?

Comment: Separators are inconsistent: some include "< ", "-", "> ". All the quotes I used are not part of the cell. Scott Crayner's answer below showed what I want the output to be! Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based solely on what you provided:

```
=IFERROR(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,">",""),"<",""),"-",REPT(" ",99)),(COLUMN(A1)-1)*99+1,99)),"")
```

Put that in the first cell, copy over and down then format as desired.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but the formula doesn't work on my excel file.. when I paste this, i get a cell that returns no value (has the formula but returns no answer)..`=IFERROR(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C32,">",""),"<",""),"-",REPT(" ",99)),(COLUMN($C32)-1)*99+1,99)),"")` --> isn't this what you have provided me with?

Comment: no, that is not what I provided:`COLUMN($C32)` should be `COLUMN(A1)` that reference should be A1 no matter where you put the first formula.